# Visual Studio 2015 RC Test Run hangs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Found a strange issue in VS 2015 - running a single unit test hangs if previous test run were interrupted by Stop Debugging.

Steps are:

1. Set a breakpoint on the first line of some test method.
2. Start that test under debugger, wait for breakpoint hit.
3. Hit `Shift+F5` or `Debugging`/`Stop Debugging`.
4. Start that single test again - it hangs on start somewhere in `te.processhost.managed.exe` native code.

Restarting the VS or just running all tests by hitting `Run All` helps, but only until the next `Shift+F5` hit.

I was able to reproduce it both locally and on clean Azure VS 2015 RC VM, so it looks like a but, not just some machine-specific glitch.

Switching `Test` / `Test Settings` / `Default Processor Architecture` from default `X86` to `X64` works for me, as it enables old `vstest` execution engine.

[This issue on MS Connect Site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1331662/test-run-hangs-on-start-if-previous-run-was-interrupted-by-shift-f5-stop-debugging).

Are there are any other known workarounds?

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report bugs.

Comment: @HansPassant I already reported it to MS Connect, just trying to find some workaround for it (other than switching to old execution engine)